# How to configure AudienceRestriction for AWS SAML endpoint in Keycloak

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, saml, keycloak

We are mapping Keycloak roles to AWS roles within our SAML client via a custom SAMLAttributeStatementMapper and have successfully been able to generate a valid SAML response via Keycloak.

In order to be able to use the AWS SAML endpoint (*https://signin.aws.amazon.com/saml*) one must provide either *https://signin.aws.amazon.com/saml* or *urn:amazon:webservices* as "Audience" within the "AudienceRestriction" tag.

So far we have found no way of doing that in the Keycloak documentation. There is an AudienceRestrictionType but we have no idea how to use it.

Comment: Would you mind providing a sample SAMLResponse ?

Comment: Sure, here's a response: https://gist.github.com/recalcitrant/a4d93760e097246eff02172410e043d3
You can see that Keycloak automatically put the client "com:vdenotaris:spring:sp" into the Audience tag so we're wondering how to manipulate that from within the Keycloak api.

Comment: the value of the  'Audience' is the EntityID of the SAML SP entity. On KeyCloack side this is named 'ClientID' for whatever reason.